# How can I make Enemy follow the player in unity

Tags: unity, 2d, ai, platform

I have a 2d platform game where I want the enemy to follow the player for some time

Currently the enemy constantly follows the player -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

  
 public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {
  
    public float speed = 0.5f;
    public Transform Player;
    
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 displacement = Player.position -transform.position;
        displacement = displacement.normalized;
        if (Vector2.Distance (Player.position, transform.position) > 1.0f) {
            transform.position += (displacement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                        
        }
        
    }
    
 }
```

How can I make the enemy only follow in certain areas or for x seconds long?

Comment: Well, you know already how to trigger a trap. Use the same logic to start the following the player. You have as well already a time in your code (`Time.deltaTime`). Just add these together while you are following and once you are over your timeLimit, stop the following.

Comment: but how do I limit the space the enemy can move in cause he just goes to the start from where he is